# Getting url helpers to have correct domain for staging app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production, staging

I have a domain, www.example.com, and an app hosted on heroku.  I use url helpers in e-mails which link back to pages on the app.  For production, that is www.example.com/etc.

I have set up staging deployment on heroku as well, at adjective-noun-xxxx.  When using the app in staging, I want the url helpers to link to the staging app at adjective-noun-xxxx.herokuapp.com/etc, but when used in staging they are still pointing to www.example.com/etc, and therefor my staging app does not work correctly.

How can I get the url helpers in the staging app to include the staging app domain, and not the production app domain?

Answer (score 0):

In this railscast this is covered.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email